# What's the name used for lines representing text in a sketch?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

What's the name for the five horizontal lines shown here in each of the page icons? The lines are placeholders for text in a sketch.

There is a specific term used for these lines in the publishing / graphic arts / cartooning industry; I've seen it before but can't for the life of me remember what they are called.

[image]

Comment: what's wrong with *lines*?

Comment: or *text lines*

Comment: there's a specific name for them in publishing jargon, but I can't remember what it is

Comment: maybe they are icons?

Comment: not the icons themselves, the 5 lines in each page icon. There is a specific term used for these in the publishing / graphic design industry.

Comment: cartoons have their own weird lingo: http://www.fastcodesign.com/1673017/quimps-plewds-and-grawlixes-the-secret-language-of-comic-strips

Comment: You may have more luck asking at  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: placeholders...?

Comment: [baselines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the term I was looking for is **greeking**.

http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/G/greeking.html :

> (1) The approximation of text characters on a screen display. Greeking is often used by word processors that support a preview function. In preview mode, the word processor attempts to show what a document will look like when printed. Frequently, however, the graphics display capabilities of the monitor are not sufficient to show text at a small size. To give a general idea of what the text will look like and how page layout will appear, the word processor uses graphics symbols to approximate the text. These symbols suggest greek letters, hence the term greeking.

also https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19048/24205

and [this historical snippet from a 1987 issue of InfoWorld magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=1TAEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA45): (I probably learned the term from using Ventura Publisher back in the late 80's; WYSIWYG page redraw sometimes took 10-20 seconds, and our laser printer took 3-5 minutes per page depending on the amount of data)

> Ventura also offers text greeking to further speed up page display. *Greeking* means substituting gray lines for actual text, so screen drawing doesn't have to recreate actual letters. Ventura can show a full page with eight levels of increasing text greeking: the more text greeked, the faster the redraw. We tested redrawing speed at the two extremes: with all text showing, and with all text completely greeked.